# `\dimexpr` with multiplication by real number and with parenthesis

Tags: dimensions, dimension-expressions

I wish to draw an object with `tikz` by a macro, therefore I have to calculate expressions like:

defined by:

```
\newcommand{\myhexagon}{2}{...}

\newcommand{\myobject}{2}{
 \myheaxgon{#1}{0.5*#2}
 \myhexagon{0.89*#1-4mm}{0.79*(#1-(0.89*#1-4mm))+#2}}
}
```

called by (e.g):

```
\myobject{2cm}{3mm}
\myobject{12mm}{3mm}
```

I've tried to solve with

```
\newcommand{\myobject}{2}{
 \def\const{0.89}
 \def\constII{0.79}

 \myheaxgon{#1}{0.5*#2}
 \myheaxgon{\the\dimexpr \const#1 -4mm\relax}{\the\dimexpr\constII\the\dimexpr#1-\the\dimexpr\const#1-4mm\relax\relax+#2\relax}
}
```

(viz. replace '0.89*' by '\const' and '()' by '`\the\dimexpr ... \relax`') but I failed. Does anyone have some idea?

Comment: Can you provide an MWE?

Comment: For a start `\newcommand{\myobject}{2}{` must be `\newcommand{\myobject}[2]{` (square brackets around the number of parameters. Same for `myhexagon`.

Answer (score 6):

Let's analyze what happens with `\myobject{2cm}{3mm}`. First the inner `\dimexpr`:

```
\the\dimexpr\const#1-4mm\relax
```

Macro parameter substitution is just that: text substitution. So when `#1=2cm` this becomes

```
\the\dimexpr\0.892cm-4mm\relax
```

not a multiplcation. If you want to multiply `\const` with `#1`, use `\const\dimexpr#1\relax`, like you have done with `\constII`. So the inner one becomes:

```
\the\dimexpr\const\dimexpr#1\relax-4mm\relax
```

With these parameters the value becomes `39.26477pt`.

Now we substitute this is the outer expression. This will become then:

```
\the\dimexpr\constII\the\dimexpr#1-39.26477pt\relax+#2\relax
```

Now substitute the parameters and you get:

```
\the\dimexpr0.79\the\dimexpr2cm-39.26477pt\relax+3mm\relax
```

Now again we have an inner expression:

```
\the\dimexpr2cm-39.26477pt\relax
```

This gives `42.9589pt`. But note: because you use `\the`, you get a text, not a length value. So with the textual substitution in the outer expression, you get:

```
\the\dimexpr0.7942.9589pt+3mm\relax
```

And instead of a multiplication, you get an illegal number with two decimal points. Lesson: **don't use `\the` inside expressions**.

With these corrections the final expression becomes:

```
\the\dimexpr\constII\dimexpr#1-\dimexpr\const\dimexpr#1\relax-4mm\relax\relax+#2\relax
```

which gives `22.47186pt`. Whether that is the expected answer, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `xparse` and `expl3`, which features a powerful and expandable module for floating point computations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpdim}{m}
 {
  \fp_to_dim:n { round(#1,5) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\const}{0.89}
\newcommand{\constII}{0.79}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Henri}

\newcommand\henriobject[2]{%
  \henrihexagon{#1}{0.5*#2}%
  \henrihexagon{\const*#1-4mm}{\constII*(#1-(\const*#1-4mm))+#2}%
}
\newcommand\henrihexagon[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult\
  and
  \pgfmathparse{#2}\pgfmathresult\par
}

\henriobject{2cm}{3mm}
\henriobject{12mm}{3mm}

\section{Piet}

\newcommand{\pietobject}[2]{%
  \piethexagon{\the\dimexpr#1\relax}{\the\dimexpr0.5\dimexpr#2\relax\relax}%
  \piethexagon{%
    \the\dimexpr\const\dimexpr#1\relax-4mm\relax
  }{%
    \the\dimexpr\constII\dimexpr#1-(\const\dimexpr#1\relax-4mm)\relax+#2\relax
  }%
}
\newcommand{\piethexagon}[2]{%
  #1 and #2\par
}

\pietobject{2cm}{3mm}
\pietobject{12mm}{3mm}

\section{\texttt{expl3}}

\newcommand{\myobject}[2]{%
  \myhexagon{\fpdim{#1}}{\fpdim{0.5*#2}}%
  \myhexagon
    {\fpdim{\const*#1-4mm}}
    {\fpdim{\constII*(#1-(\const*#1-4mm))+#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\myhexagon}[2]{%
  #1 and #2\par
}

\myobject{2cm}{3mm}
\myobject{12mm}{3mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the results are much alike to each other, with differences only at the fourth decimal digit.

The big differences is that the solutions with `xparse` and `\dimexpr` are fully expandable, whereas the one with `\pgfmathparse` isn't.

The `xparse` syntax is much more friendly than `\dimexpr`, essentially identical to the one for `\pgfmathparse`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `pgfmath` if you are using TikZ anyway.  Just insert your mathematical expression in `\pgfmathparse` (even including dimensions) and retrieve the result from `\pgfmathresult` (in `pt`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\myhexagon[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult\
  and
  \pgfmathparse{#2}\pgfmathresult\par
}

\newcommand\myobject[2]{%
  \myhexagon{#1}{0.5*#2}%
  \myhexagon{0.89*#1-4mm}{0.79*(#1-(0.89*#1-4mm))+#2}%
}

\myobject{2cm}{3mm}
\myobject{12mm}{3mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]